# how to connect Web sql in node-webkit app?

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite, node-webkit

Currently am creating application using node-webkit.I can see the local database in chrome browser.But i would like to connect the database from mozilla sqllite add on..Is this possible.previously the database is creating inside user-directory of my app.I have another one doubt. For every login am emptying the database that is also not working.

Answer (score 1):

In the SQLite Manager, you can "Export Database". That will give you all the SQL commands needed install that as a local database in your node-webkit app. Here's a code snippet how I'm handling all those commands:

```
        var importDatabase = function(all_sql_commands) {

            var index = 0;
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            nextRecord(index, all_sql_commands);

            function nextRecord(index, all_sql_commands) {

                if (index < all_sql_commands.length) {
                    db.transaction(function(tx) {
                        tx.executeSql(all_sql_commands[index],
                                [],
                                function(transaction, results) {
                                    nextRecord(++index, all_sql_commands);
                                },
                                function(transaction, error) {
                                    console.log(error.message + ". Trying to execute: " + all_sql_commands[index]);
                                    nextRecord(++index, all_sql_commands);
                                });
                    });
                } else {
                    deferred.resolve("all done");
                }
            }
            ;
            return deferred.promise;
        }
```

I have this code in a factory and is recursive so only one command is processed at a time. This is how i'm initizlizing the database on entry into the database:

```
configFactory.database().then(function(results) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    deferred.resolve(results);
    return deferred.promise;
}).then(function(results) {
    sqlManager.exportTables().then(function(tables) { // get a list of tables
        sqlManager.dropTables(tables).then(function() {// make sure they are clean
            sqlManager.importSqlCommands(results.import_sql_file_name).then(function(all_sql_commands) { // read in importSQL.txt, CREATE TABLE first, then INSERT INTO's next
                sqlManager.importDatabase(all_sql_commands).then(function(results) { // loop through the commands and run the SQL scripts.
                    $scope.databaseInstalled = "Database installed";
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

My config factory:

```
define(['angular', 'sherpaManagerFactories'], function(angular) {

var databaseConfig = window.requireNode('./app/node/config/database');
angular.module('sherpaManager.factories').factory('configFactory', ['$q', function($q) {

        var database = function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve(databaseConfig.database);
            return deferred.promise;
        };

        return {
            database: database
        };
    }]); 
});
```

and finally my databaseConfig itself:

```
var Q = window.requireNode('q');

var deferred = Q.defer();

var database = function() {
    var obj = {};
    obj.database_name = "SherpaManager"; // TODO figure out how to pass this into the sqlManager factory. Right now it's hard coded into the sqlManager
    obj.import_sql_file_name = "./config/SherpaManager.sql";
    deferred.resolve(obj);
    return deferred.promise;
}

module.exports.database = database();
```

Hope this helps